# Как подсчитать количество привязанных записей?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Есть 2 таблицы:
`table` (`id`)
и
`mapping_table` (`id`, `mapped_id`)
CONSTRAINT `fk` FOREIGN KEY (`mapped_id`)
REFERENCES `table` (`id`)
с соотношением 1:М.
Как подсчитать количество строк таблицы `table`, для которых в `mapping_table` имеются связанные строки (количество связанных не важно).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример запроса:

```sql
select count(distinct t.id)
from table t
join mapping_table mt on t.id = mt.mapped_id
```

Если нужно всего лишь количество по `ID` без доп информации, то можно еще проще :

```sql
select count(distinct mt.mapped_id)
from mapping_table mt
```